# How to make a Javascript Link activate an Existing Contact form on the site?

Tags: javascript

I dont know if this will make sense, but I have this site: http://commentgreendrycleaning.com/, the site has a contact form, but its all javascript activated.

when you go to the site, If you choose 3 stars you will see the contact form. If you choose 5 stars, it will go to another page, with logos. Under those logos it says "If you dont have an please give us feedback here". So my goal is to make the word "here", link to the contact form. But its all javascript, so I dont know how to do that?

Basically make it link to the contact page or activate...?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you don't know HTML? Or you wrote it all in document.write or what

Comment: Have you tried asking the person who coded it?

Comment: No, It doesnt work like that. There is no direct link to use a standard HTML link code. Its javascript transitions. Check out the site, youll see what Im saying. So I dont know how to activate the contact form when on a certain page.

Comment: Don't you have access to the javascript code?

Comment: Yes, but I dont get it, what do I need access to? This is the code for the contact page: <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="tellCo" class="orange-btn tellUs noJoke" style="float: left">Tell us about it</a> when you look at the view source of the page.  So i tried using that line, but it doesnt call up anything...idk

Answer (score 0):

I find that when a link's href is "javascript:void()", the original coder wired up a click event handler to perform the desired function.  That is what has happened here.

The anchor with the id "tellCo" (The "Tell us about it" link") has a click event setup in the window load() function in common.js.  The code that sets up the link's click event is on approximately line 265.  See the code snippet cut from your code below:

```
//screen 1 new : start  
$('#tellCo').click(function() {
    $('.bad-exp').addClass('fadeOutLeft').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#badContent').addClass('fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.s4').fadeIn(1000).addClass('fadeInRight');
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.s4').removeClass('animated fadeInRight');
//      $('.help-con').remove();
        $('.help-btn').removeClass('active');
    }, 2000);



});
//end
```

The simplest solution would to just call the click event on the link, such as:

```
$('#tellCo').click();
```

But... personally, I would extract the inline function out of the event binding and place it into a separate function that could be called independently and be a little more maintainable (IMHO), such as:

```
function tellMeAboutIt() {
    $('.bad-exp').addClass('fadeOutLeft').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#badContent').addClass('fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.s4').fadeIn(1000).addClass('fadeInRight');
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.s4').removeClass('animated fadeInRight');
 //     $('.help-con').remove();
        $('.help-btn').removeClass('active');
    }, 2000);
}
```

Then replace the original click event setup with:

```
$('#tellCo').click(function() { tellMeAboutIt(); });
```

This way you can call tellMeAboutIt() whereever and whenever you like.

So, for the simpler solution, add this to the window.load() function:

```
$('#yourNewLink').click(function() { $('#tellCo').click(); });
```

'yourNewLink' is whatever the 'id' property is of the new link you are creating.  the new link would look something like this:

```
<a href='javascript:void()' id='yourNewLink'>here</a>
```

Remember the javascript creates the click event, so the HTML is very basic.

Comment: Omg thats overwhelming lol. So I would make a new javascript file in my javascript folder, with just that code?  What would I actually put into the page source though, the html? This? --> "$('#tellCo').click(function() { tellMeAboutIt(); });"

Comment: or for the simpler solution you listed, where does "$('#tellCo').click();" go? In the html code?

Comment: Updated my answer (at the bottom) to show an implementation of the simpler solution.

Comment: So I add "$('#yourNewLink').click(function() { $('#tellCo').click(); });" to the bottom of the common javascript file?.... then  put this into the html: "<a href='javascript:void()' id='yourNewLink'>here</a>"  ?

Comment: No... add it to the window.load() function in common.js.  For example, add it right below the place where tellCo's click event is setup.  Then yes, the other info is in the HTML, (but I would rename the link to something more meaningful).

Comment: No, didnt work. This is the HTML where I put it: http://gyazo.com/734278e753120e3332a6be23dcbab30b   and this is the Java script common file where I put the js: http://gyazo.com/066d887171d35053dec3df0e88f6a416

Comment: You added the code inside the click event of tellCo.  Place it just after the //end. (outside the tellCo click event)